# How to rotate masked image?

Tags: ios, swift, rotation, imageview, mask

Right now my code displays a image like this

[image]
It would work if I could just rotate the image clockwise 90 degrees. How would I do this. Code is listed below. I took out some of the unnecessary lines of code for this.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {
    var screenView: UIImageView!
    var image1 = UIImage(named: "w")

    func cropImageIntoQuarterSquare(image: UIImage) -> UIImage? {
        //shape of mask
        let image = photoDispaly.image
        let maskingImage = UIImage(named: "mask5")

        //where the masking code starts
        photoDispaly.image = maskImage(image: image!, mask: maskingImage!)
        photoDispaly.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight, .flexibleBottomMargin, .flexibleRightMargin, .flexibleLeftMargin, .flexibleTopMargin]
        photoDispaly.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit // OR .scaleAspectFill
        photoDispaly.clipsToBounds = true

        let originalImageSize: CGSize = image!.size
        let smallImageSize = CGSize(width: (originalImageSize.width + 40), height: (originalImageSize.height + 40))
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(smallImageSize)
        image?.draw(at: CGPoint.zero)
        let imageResult = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        return imageResult
    }

    @IBOutlet var photoDispaly: UIImageView!

    func maskImage(image:UIImage, mask:(UIImage))->UIImage{
        let imageReference = image.cgImage
        let maskReference = mask.cgImage
        let imageMask = CGImage(maskWidth: maskReference!.width,
                                height: maskReference!.height,
                                bitsPerComponent: maskReference!.bitsPerComponent,
                                bitsPerPixel: maskReference!.bitsPerPixel,
                                bytesPerRow: maskReference!.bytesPerRow,
                                provider: maskReference!.dataProvider!, decode: nil, shouldInterpolate: true)
        let maskedReference = imageReference!.masking(imageMask!)
        let maskedImage = UIImage(cgImage:maskedReference!)
        return maskedImage
    }

    func image(_ image: UIImage, didFinishSavingWithError error: Error?, contextInfo: UnsafeRawPointer) {
        if let error = error {
            return
        } else {
            return
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you could run a transform on your UIImageView in your ViewDidLoad function

```
photoDispaly.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: M_PI/4)
```

also you may want to rename Dispaly to Display ;)

Comment: this is changing the part that is display but once the image is complied is is still 90 degrees counter clockwise off. This has not change the output image at all. At least by putting the code in the view did load section.